# How to remove database files while performing uninstallation of Java application

Tags: java, database, swing, h2

I have created a small Java Swing application. In this application for some purpose I created database files using H2 database. I created those database in user directory like

> jdbc:h2:~/mydb\classroutine

Now , the problem is, after installing this application when I want to uninstall it, those database files remains there, "I mean database files are not removing". Now I need to know how I can remove those database files while uninstalling the application.

Comment: *how* do you install or uninstall? Is there an installer package involved? Name it. If there isn't: What's involved with installation and uninstallation?

Comment: I used **Inno setup Compiler** for making the Installer file.

Comment: Doesn't that tool have an option for removal?

Comment: As far i know there is no such option for removing additional files while uninstalling.Its only remove all the helper files and folders belong in the installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a local H2 file, I would ensure that my code is able to generate the required H2 database when it does not exist. Once this is done, I would have a restart function, which shuts down all DB connections, then closes the application, but before it does this, it spawns in a separate thread a script or standalone java jar file that is able to delete the physical H2 db file.